# Associating two values in differing lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, input

At the end of my code, I want a line that states which marble has the fastest time. The issue being I need to split my inputs (which follow the format of the marble ID then the time in seconds separated by ';;') in order to convert the times in minutes and also calculate max, min and avg. How can I reassociate the two lists I have created in order to show which is the best marble?

```
def minute_converter(x):
    sec = int(x) % 60
    minutes = int(x) // 60
    print(minutes, 'mins', sec, 'secs.')


def average(x):
    avg = [int(n) for n in x]
    return sum(avg) / len(avg)


print('Marble Racer Program')

data = ['331;;591', '010;;902', '809;;030', '756;;201', '128;;382']
marble_number = [x.split(';;', 1)[0] for x in data]
marble_times = [x.split(';;', 1)[1] for x in data]
print(marble_number)
print(marble_times)

print('Marble with best time is', end=' '), minute_converter(min(marble_times))
print('Average time:', end=' '), minute_converter(average(marble_times))
print('Marble with worst time is', end=' '), minute_converter(max(marble_times))
print(f'We have seen a total of {len(marble_number)} marbles.')
```

Output:

```
Marble Racer Program
['331', '010', '809', '756', '128']
['591', '902', '030', '201', '382']
Marble with best time is 0 mins 30 secs.
Average time: 7 mins 1 secs.
Marble with worst time is 15 mins 2 secs.
We have seen a total of 5 marbles.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Store them as tuples in a single list with the time first.  Then, you can use `min` to return the winning tuple.

Comment: Why would they care one whit how you store the data internally?  You can PRINT it however you need to.  You CAN use a `key` function to `min`, but you shouldn't need to.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of two separate lists containing the runner number and time, you could have a single list of lists:

```
runners = [[int(i) for i in x.split('::')] for x in data]
# [[123, 90], [101, 310], [99, 120]]
```

This handles the conversion of the data to integers while parsing the data, so you don't have to do it while processing.

Now, find the runners with the max and min time:

```
slowest_runner = max(runners, key=lambda item: item[1]) # [101, 310]
fastest_runner = min(runners, key=lambda item: item[1]) # [123, 90]
```

The runner id is the `0`th element of these lists, and the time is the `1`th element.

```
print(f"The fastest runner is {fastest_runner[0]} with a time of {sec_convert(fastest_runner[1])}")
# The fastest runner is 123 with a time of 1 minutes and 30 seconds

print(f"The slowest runner is {slowest_runner[0]} with a time of {sec_convert(slowest_runner[1])}")
# The slowest runner is 101 with a time of 5 minutes and 10 seconds
```

To find the total time, we need to add all the `1`th element of all the items in `runners`.

```
total_time = sum(item[1] for item in runners) # 520
avg_time = total_time / len(runners) # 173.33333333333334
```

---

Note: I redefined your `sec_convert` function to *return* its result instead of printing it, so we can format our print message:

```
def sec_convert(x):
    sec = x % 60
    minutes = x // 60
    return f"{minutes} minutes and {sec} seconds"
```